# Can a full damage Ranger survive in the late game?

Tags: path-of-exile

I am just starting Path of Exile and I chose as Ranger. Since I can't reset my passive skills easily I want to know if a Ranger can manage to survive "easily" in lategame with only damage specc?
I know that I should at least put some points in % life or stun duration.

I don't want to have personal opinions, just need some facts, possible or not ?

I made this passive tree [My passive tree](http://www.pathofexile.com/passive-skill-tree/AAAAAgIAr-vn6vkzlwYF-RXw51Qk_dUAxKIB0bvj_rp9ddN-m40ILu2DGY4AXs6oAbzveucK3IJ46_zFVvruDjpYBH6HGaOKmybo1usUjb8FtdQj3ajGojBxS3g6QrEwhs531PlWtMULkZrxCImTJV1owTMyAbIZz3ph63pTdEF315UFMpR_AtnGBYSm4H8rMfohdnb3yqkwfG_yOdSgn9aKFHXB2N0Nqwtyw8wGIuprJMqP2mTwQpXpX-EPq21ssw4hwLVI_5MeGtIZ1tEqW-d0YeKH2xa_8-rAUXDVcFLe-KR4wdVRRzMM_isZ1f_eJGq4N6TC)

what to change to get maximum dps?

Comment: Is this surviving required in normal or hardcore difficulty? Since in normal dieing every now and then is not a problem, in hardcore it is a fatal error.

Comment: of course normal.

Comment: I'd suggest trying to create a build with less points used, having all points used requires you to get to lvl 99 AND do one quest in a specific way in all difficulties. Where doing it in an other way might give you something even more usefull. Getting to 99 is crazy too.

Comment: of course i will put the points in 1by1 by leveling and i will not go for 99 but anyway, i want to know if this setup is ok or not :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your posted passive skilltree I'm going to say **no**. Not easily at least.

Since you took *Point Blank*, you'll need to get up close and personal with mobs, since you have nearly no life, nor options to get a lot of energy shield (no int) you'll be very squishy and you *are* going to get hit sooner or later. 
Evading everything is just not possible, so death will be your part.

Working towards a skilltree using up all points is also not the best idea, since your build will never be able to use it's full potential. It's better to build to something around 70-80 points spent, and use any points you get past that as bonus.

I don't have enough experience with a ranger to create a demo build for you though.

Answer (score 3):

That will definitely be impossible for a point blank ranger without godlike gear.  Even then, they'd likely die quite a bit.  Without point blank in a perfect world with flawless play and perfect game knowlege... possible? probably.  That said, path of exile is not a perfect world.

When I make a build and it's close range, i usually aim for about 250% health or so.  For a ranged build you can probably get away with about 200%.  All of this depends on your gear, but i've been successful starting untwinked with these numbers.

The trick to a high damage build (because health is necessary in poe) is to find very efficient damage nodes (and very efficent health nodes). I made a couple of changes to your tree: [New Passive Tree](http://www.pathofexile.com/passive-skill-tree/AAAAAgIAr-uXBgX5FfDnVCT91QDEogHRu-P-un11036bjQgu7YMZjgBe73r8xVb67g46WAR-hxmjipsm6NbrFI2_BbXUI92oxqIwcUt4OkKxMIbOd9T5VrTFC5Ga8QiJkyVdaMEzMgGyGc96dEF315UFMpR_AtnGBYSm4H8rMfohdnb3yqkwfG_yOdSgn9aKFHXB2N0NIuprJMqP2mTwQpXpX-EPq21stUj_kx4a0hnW0Spb53Rh4ofbFr_z6sBRcNVwUt74pHjB1VFHMwz-KxnV_97-CSchlchnoId2Sn0s6bQa4sslP217VUsmlSP27_BaSA==)

I took out the excess dex nodes (you dont need any more than you get traveling the tree) and the points in the attack speed near the bottom. i put those into the same amount of attack speed in the starting area(for bows) and was able to get the really good health node thick skin on the bottom.

I also took out a couple of less efficient defensive nodes and placed them into health, which you really need more.

This build still needs a lot of work.  You should get it to 100 points, as hard as that is, because max level is very hard to get to. This means you'll have to sacrifice some damage and get some health as well, though not too much more.  I would also suggest getting nullification in the shadow starting area, itll really help with resistances.

I love making up new character builds, wish you the best of luck :-)